# Reversing elements in a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a numpy array of top 2 labels:

```
n =  [['20011' '20048']
     ['20011' '20048']
     ['20011' '20048']
     ['20011' '20048']]
```

I want to get them in the reverse order:

```
[['20048' '20011']
 ['20048' '20011']
 ['20048' '20011']]
```

How can I do so while keeping the format the same?

Code till now:

```
n = model1.classes_[order[:,-5:]]
print(n)
r = [p[::-1] for p in n]
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[array(['20048', '20011'], 
      dtype='|S5'), array(['20048', '20011'], 
      dtype='|S5'), array(['20048', '20011'], 
      dtype='|S5'), array(['20048', '20011'], 
      dtype='|S5')]
```

Need to try getting rid of the `dtypes` and keeping only the reversed array.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you want to get a proper answer you need to update your question with the code that you have tried so far and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `[L[::-1] for L in lists]`

Comment: @minks,  add the actual output from printing your array

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: added

Comment: I edited my answer already, if you want the end result to end up in a file you can do what I have in the edit

Comment: You also see the dtype because you now have  a lists of numpy arrays, you don't need to use python logic at all to reverse the subarrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Then a simple list comprehension like this

```
[li[::-1] for li in l]
```

gives you the desired output:

```
[['c', 'b', 'a'], ['f', 'e', 'd']]
```

**EDIT:**

As you changed your question:

Let's say you now have an array of arrays:

```
import numpy as np
l2 = np.array([np.array(['a', 'b', 'c']), np.array(['d', 'e', 'f'])])
```

Then you can do the following to get rid of the `dtypes`:

```
map(list, l2[:, ::-1])
```

which gives you:

```
[['c', 'b', 'a'], ['f', 'e', 'd']]
```

But from your question it is still hard to tell what exact output format you want.

Comment: I tried doing it with a smaller list: [['20011' '20048']
 ['20011' '20048']
 ['20011' '20048']
 ['20011' '20048']]
 
and received something like: 
array(['20048', '20011'], 
      dtype='|S5'), array(['20048', '20011'], 
      dtype='|S5'), array(['20048', '20011'], 
      dtype='|S5'), array(['20048', '20011'], 
      dtype='|S5')]

Why is the dtype being displayed?

Comment: @minks, you have numpy arrays not python lists

Comment: Are you sure you work with lists and not with numpy arrays!?

Comment: Oh right! Is there a way I could carry out the same procedure but get ride of the dtypes. It seems to be working partially though by reversing 20048 and 20011

Comment: @cleb: yes, my bad. Have updated the question. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: It works also for arrays, no problem. Why is displaying the dtype a problem? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @cleb: I am actually writing the output to a file and displaying on a webpage. So the dtype would look a little off.

Comment: @minks: I updated my answer. I am not sure which output format you have in mind; if you are more precise about it I could come up with something which suits you better.

Comment: @cleb: It worked perfectly. Thanks. I have accepted the answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

Your lists seem be missing commas so you actually have one string per list but you can do it *inplace* with `list.reverse` if you want to modify the original sublists:

```
for sub in lists:
     sub.reverse()
```

You actually have a numpy array so presuming it is in the correct format you can:

```
In [50]: arr
Out[50]: 
array([['20015', '20013', '20044', '20001', '20002'],
       ['20002', '20015', '20001', '20013', '20070']], 
      dtype='|S5')

In [51]: arr[:,::-1]
Out[51]: 
array([['20002', '20001', '20044', '20013', '20015'],
       ['20070', '20013', '20001', '20015', '20002']], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

To save to a file something like:

```
In [57]: arr[:,::-1].tofile("out.txt",sep=",")

In [58]: cat out.txt
20002,20001,20044,20013,20015,20070,20013,20001,20015,20002
```

If you want one row per line savetxt:

```
In [94]: np.savetxt("out.txt",arr[:,::-1],fmt="%s")

In [95]: cat out.txt
20002 20001 20044 20013 20015
20070 20013 20001 20015 20002
```

Comment: You could also do it in one line: `[sub.reverse() for sub in lists]`

Comment: @zondo, true but you would be using a list comp for side effects and creating a list of None's

Comment: @zondo This doesn't work,I got [None, None, None, None]

Comment: Certainly; that's why it's just a comment.

Comment: @RichardRublev: Don't assign anything to that.  My comment would be executed on it's own.  The reversing is done in place.

Answer (score 0):

## Another List Comprehension Approach

Being a big fan of list comprehensions, I approached similar to Cleb, but with a reverse method from the list class instead using the `list_name[::-1]` approach.

```
l1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
[l1[i].reverse() for i in range(len(l1))]
```

yields ...

```
[[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [10, 9, 8, 7]]
```

The key is to not set the comprehension equal to anything.